# how I get values from several MVC3 Telerik Controls on a button press and filter other controls on the screen?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc

I have a couple of Telerik DropDownList controls and a RangeSlider that I want to set values on then have a button which applies this to another set of controls (filtering data down)

How do I get the values of the 3 different controls and apply it to say Charts?

Is the only way to do it with Client Side API and javascript?  or can I pull it somehow with the model?

I tried doing a HTTP Post and the model returned to the Action was all null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript for sure. When the button is clicked you will need to use the **rebind** method of the Chart object (check here how to use it properly http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-chart-client-api-and-events.html) to send your values to the server and rebind the Chart

Also you will need to use the client side methods of the [DropDowns](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#value) and the [Slider](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-slider-client-api-and-events.html#value) - to get the values.